# Последовательное рисование линий

Tags: javascript, canvas

Всем доброго времени суток, возникла проблема с рисованием линий, код следующий:

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

DrawPoint(ctx, 50);

function DrawPoint(ctx, size) {
  DrawSerif(ctx, ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2)
  DrawSerif(ctx, ctx.canvas.width / 2 + size, ctx.canvas.height / 2)
  DrawSerif(ctx, ctx.canvas.width / 2 + 2 * size, ctx.canvas.height / 2)
}

function DrawSerif(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + 5)
  ctx.lineTo(x, y - 5)
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: #ddd;"></canvas>
```

Проблема в том, что рисуется только последняя вызванная функция DrawSerif, может кто-то подсказать как избежать затирания предыдущих засечек?

Comment: `ctx.fill();` → `ctx.stroke();` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, да, это помогло, спасибо

Comment: ну или closePath перед fill

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, closePath перед fill - не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

метод [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill) закрашивает область, ограниченную контуром.

В данном случае контур не замкнут, поэтому и закрашивать нечего.

Если нужно закрасить линию (границу контура) - стоит использовать [`stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke)

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

DrawPoint(ctx, 50);

function DrawPoint(ctx, size) {
  DrawSerif(ctx, ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2)
  DrawSerif(ctx, ctx.canvas.width / 2 + size, ctx.canvas.height / 2)
  DrawSerif(ctx, ctx.canvas.width / 2 + 2 * size, ctx.canvas.height / 2)
}

function DrawSerif(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + 5)
  ctx.lineTo(x, y - 5)
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: #ddd;"></canvas>
```